# is it possible to log & graph twisted.reactor?

Tags: debugging, logging, twisted

I'm doing a lot of asynchronous programming lately using python and twisted. I think it's a big step forward in code quality and development speed (if you do it right) :D

One big problem with async programming is - IMHO - the code could be sometimes hard to read if you're not the original coder. And that's the point, where my project idea drops in:

**Idea:**
I want to see what the reactor is doing. For now in a log, later in form of an graph (graph is out of scope here). More precise:

- where callbacks are added to deferrds
- where deferreds are fired
- List item
- which methods are called in syncronous parts of an application.

**Question**
I didn't find answers to this:

- is there something (an open sorce project, ...) which I should look at? Think I'm not the only one who thinks about doing that :p
- do you know a way to log, what the reactor is doing? I've read a lot about twisted logging, but i didn't find the answer, how to do this 'the right way'. Do I have to overwrite the mainloop-class and add the logging there? It doesn't seem the right solution to me. Something tells me twisted has a better way to do that :)
- Sure I'm used to use debugging. But I never (until now) implemented debugging in python. How could I register as debugger to get the needed data (and possible intercept from the high level graph view I want to implement later)?

I hope you could help me with ideas, how to accomplish such funcionality. I'm sure your feedback will directly benefit in a better solution :) 
Btw: I want to do this in an open source application. Feel free to contact me if you want to get involved.

King regards, Florian.

Comment: You ought to ask your questions separately. Each of those 3 questions is pretty huge; all 3 together would be a small novel :).

Comment: Yea, you're right. 'cause they are related I think about them in one piece. I'll split them (as soon I find some spare time today). Thanks.

Comment: today = some day in the next 2 weeks :) busy times.